# Clickatell SMSes with special GSM characters through REST API

Tags: c#, encoding, sms, sms-gateway, clickatell

I am using the Clickatell REST API for sending SMSes. I need to send some special characters (like Ä) which are all available in the GSM 03.38 standard (and in latin-1 as well). So, I don't want to use unicode. However, no matter how I send the message, I don't get what I want. Either the message is correctly saved in Clickatell but comes with strange symbols on the device or I encode the message and then get hex letter in Clickatell and nothing at all on the device. In the FAQ there is a solution for the HTTP API but it didn't help me for the REST API. I contacted support but I have been already waiting 3 days for an answer. Does someone here have an experience with the API?

Here are some of my unsuccessful tries:

**Data correctly displayed on Clickatell page but not in the SMS**

```
string data = clickatellEncoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(data, clickatellEncoding,
    jsonContentType
```

**Hex letter on Clickatell page, no SMS received**

```
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(data);
byte[] clickatellBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, clickatellEncoding, utfBytes);
data = clickatellEncoding.GetString(clickatellBytes);
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(data, clickatellEncoding), 
    jsonContentType);
```

I also wrote an own converter from utf-8 to GSM 03.38, the result was again hex letters on Clickatell page an no SMS.

Any ideas what else I could try?

*The Clickatell encoding is latin-1.*  So, theoretically I should send everything in latin-1 and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

The current Clickatell REST API expects Windows-1252 character set. If you adhere to this and the characters still do not get delivered, the support team will need to investigate the delivery routes to the network(s) you are sending to.

Comment: Well, there are German networks and the devices I am using get all the time SMSes with such characters. So, I was thinking that I have some error in the implementation.